# How to set url in vue for a external backend api and a devserver api

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm setting up an app using Vue, and want to create an API Service where on production should point to api.domain.com.br and on dev should point to 127.0.0.1:1337.

My API is using axios to make requests like so:

```
axios.post('/api/v2/plan', plan)
```

My vue.config.js has a this proxy solution:

```
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:1337',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      },
    }
  },
```

I could create a service from axios and import it on api:

```
import axios from 'axios';


const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.domain.com.br'
});


export default client;
```

But then it wont work with dev proxy set on vue.config.js

**synthesis:**

App on production is at app.domain.com.br

Api on production is at api.domain.com.br

App on dev is at 127.0.0.1:8080

Api on dev is at 127.0.0.1:1337

When i build this app, it should use api.domain.com.br on axios calls.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use an env file with a base url variable

.env.development

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:1337
```

.env.production

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URL=https://api.domain.com.br
```

then in your axios

```
const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL
});
```

`.env.development` is automatically loaded for the command `vue-cli-service serve`
`.env.production` is automatically loaded for the command `vue-cli-service build`

You can also use local .env files which are gitignored by default in vue cli projects. See [vue's](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html) documentation for more info.

Comment: very nice info and clearly explained.. just one question:
Do you store these files .env.development & .env.production in the root dir of your vue project (like vue.config.js) ?
-- UPDATE--
disregard that question, found the solution here: https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-vue-js-273eba0102b0

Comment: another more valid question where I can't find the answer to : In the above example.. do you remove the info inside vue.config.js (that refers to /api) in the given solution?
And... I have almost the same setup, except I don't have an axios service and in fact don't know exactly how to set this up :s

Comment: @George in my setup axios looks at the base url from the env files. What do you have in the vue.config.js that relates to the api? I have not seen this before

Comment: how do I refer to VUE_APP_BASE_URL inside my components where I do my axios thing? this.axios.post(VUE_APP_BASE_URL, { action: 'loadCompanies' })

Comment: @George I add the baseUrl to the axios config (https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults) so something like `axios.defaults.baseUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL`. Now when I call axios methods I only have to add the remaining url so something like `axios.get('/items')` would call the url `https://mybaseurl.com/items`